# Make relational data unreadable to developers with credentials

Tags: security, encryption, obfuscation, public-key

I'm trying to implement a simple system where some relational data is hidden even from me the developer and sysadmin. I'm not sure what is the right approach and here's my main use case for ServiceX:

User A has a private "**/secretURL**" and controls what is shown on the page. Right now, it shows "**A**", "**B**" and "**C**".

User A uses ServiceX to create a link he wants to share with User B that only shows "**A**" and "**B**". ServiceX returns "**/customPublicURL**". If User A updates the content on the page of the secret URL e.g. removes B entirely, "**/customPublicURL**" should not show B anymore.

What I want is a system that is capable of keeping track of the "**/customPublicURL**" -> "**/secretURL**" with respect to permissions, but I want no one, including me, to be able to see the link between **"/customPublicURL"** and **"/secretURL"** that was generated by User A.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ahm the question is heaps too broad, but basically make it so your shared URL contains a cryptographically secure enveloped parameter that can then be checked by your code to retrieve relevant data. Technically, however, someone in your organisation is responsible for hosting/setting things up and THAT person would be able to obtain the keys needed to decrypt that envelope. If, however, you make it so that person does not have other access to the system you're at least mitigating the attack scope somewhat.